# Is there one way to view cpu opcache parameter infos like size or associativity in linux?

Tags: linux, cpu, cpu-cache

I recently use `perf` to benchmark the program. It has one event
`de_dis_uops_from_decoder.opcache_dispatched` which shows "Count of dispatched Ops from OpCache." (here is the [related source code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a901a3568fd26ca9c4a82d8bc5ed5b3ed844d451/tools/perf/pmu-events/arch/x86/amdzen2/other.json#L16)). Then I want to get something like cacheline size which L2 cache uses in op cache. The [wikichip](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_2#Memory_Hierarchy) shows zen2 (I use ryzen 7 4800h cpu) has "8 Op line size" and "Each entry contains up to 8 sequential instructions" about op cache (The amd patent file referenced by wikichip also says about the how op cache implemented).

I know how to get L1~L3 cache infos after searching the web.

I want to get more infos which may be specific to my cpu than the above wikichip link offers. Then is there one linux tool to view **op cache** conveniently if possible? Or how to use codes to get it if possible?

Here is how to view L1~L3 cache infos which includes "sets","COHERENCY-SIZE"(i.e. cacheline size),etc :

```bash
$ lscpu --cache
NAME ONE-SIZE ALL-SIZE WAYS TYPE        LEVEL SETS PHY-LINE COHERENCY-SIZE
L1d       32K     256K    8 Data            1   64        1             64
L1i       32K     256K    8 Instruction     1   64        1             64
L2       512K       4M    8 Unified         2 1024        1             64
L3         4M       8M   16 Unified         3 4096        1             64
```

Comment: Caches are transparent to software and due to how they work simply trying to read their contents would likely completely change what you were trying to read. Possible duplicate at SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799938/show-cpu-cache-and-register-contents-during-debugging

Comment: Thanks. From your link offered, it seems impossible to get the states of caches with the **running** program. Maybe I didn't describe my question clearly. I has updated. Then is there one method to view something like **cacheline size** in byte unit with opcache, just like how L2 cache related information is got? Hope I have understood what you said.